# Algolia Keyboard Navigation on range and price slider

Tags: javascript, accessibility, algolia

For accessibility reasons I need to control
**Algolia** price slider using the keyboard.

Cant find any documantation on it
https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/range-slider/js/.

Does anyone know if there is a way to enable this functionality?